# How do Services slot in with the Repository Pattern in Android Development?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, service, repository-pattern

I am a relatively new android developer and am currently in the early stages of a new project. I am using Compose and have a solid idea of what my application will do.

Based on my research I have found out that the Repository Pattern is the recommended one. My understanding is the following Activity <-> ViewModel <-> Repo Interface <-> Repository <-> Data sources(Such as remote or local database).

My problem is where should a service start/bind and/or be used.  For example, I have a service that handles location using Google's API and want to use that data to control Google Maps. Should I in this case start the service inside the ViewModel? The repository?

I tried to read many stackoverflow posts, read the documentation and watch tutorials, but all of them only cover how to deal with databases such as Room.

My first stockoverflow post and I am ready to get destroyed, but hope for some assistance!

Comment: "where should a service start/bind and/or be used" -- usually never. Few apps need a service. "I have a service that handles location using Google's API and want to use that data to control Google Maps" -- why are you using a service? Assuming that you do really need a service, what are the triggers for when that service needs to start and stop?

Comment: @CommonsWare Part of the application will be tracking the location of the user and storing it. Initially will be manually/user initiated, but plan to make it automated(in the background).

Comment: "plan to make it automated" -- I am uncertain what you mean by "automated" in this context. My guess is that the right answer long term is that your service is not started by anything in your main set of classes (the <-> bits from your question). Instead, it will be started by whatever is handling the "automated" aspect (e.g., Firebase Cloud Messaging).

Comment: @CommonsWare By automated I mean it periodically checks in the background if the user has moved or the google/correct way of doing this.

Comment: @Dralexus On modern ANdroid you'd need background location permission to do this, granted by the user at runtime.  In other words, it's not something you can rely on working.